# Android Studio and Alfresco mobile SDK

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, alfresco

it's a simple question, but someone knows or have a guide on how to import Alfresco Mobile SDK in Android Studio (gradle). 
I'm having difficulties on this front and I'm 98% sure that it's a gradle build project issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For the moment we don't officially support the integration of Alfresco SDK with Android Studio. It's something we think we might address in 2014.

But as far as I know, the main problem is the support of Android Project Library and the project structure. In maven project libraries are apklib file and in Gradle it's an aar. the project structure is also not the same between the 2 builds system so it might requires some changes that's why for the moment we stay with maven.

If you don't plan to use Android SDK APK library you can simply import all jar dependencies
inside your build.gradle like :

- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-android-client:0.10.0
- org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.6.1-RC1
- org.alfresco.cmis.client:alfresco-opencmis-extension:0.5-ANDROID
- org.alfresco.mobile.android.sdk:alfresco-mobile-android-sdk:1.2.0

For more information with Gradle & Android let's have a look at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide